# update a form and not load or reload page

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, codeigniter

I have a simple command:

```
<?php echo form_open("sales/add",array('id'=>'add_item_form')); ?>
```

How can I make this command so it just updates the form, without reload or redirection. I dont even need to see the form. I have tried all sorts of methods, but wondering if there is something simple here I am missing. I just need to post the data.
This is what is outputted by codeigniter.

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1/index.php/sales/add" method="post" id="add_item_form">
    <label id="item_label" for="item">
</form>
```

I have tried jquery but still does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: may i know which one u have to update without redirecting or reload.?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [iframes](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/submit-form-to-iframe-in-same-page-510807.html) or xml http requests ([ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need jquery ajax function to do that. Maybe you have tried different jquery function. Check this out:

```
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
```

There are some examples in that link you can look at.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the path of your controller? Then you can use jQuery to do that. Check this plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I tried malsup but couldnt get it to work. maybe it is some conflict. I know the path to the controller. I am not sure how I would impliment it though. I am quite new to codeigniter. Do you have any further info. thanks.

Comment: post the code you have made with the jquery plugin, plus the error that is happening

Comment: Managed to get it working with malsup. cheers. If anyone needs to know include jquery and     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script> 
 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            
            $('#add_item_form').ajaxForm(function() { 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>

Comment: How do I close this. I am quite knew here and not sure on procedure. Thanks for help. Simon